# Is there a function in python for the fourth, fifth e.t.c. root?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program which uses the root that a user defines, for example:

1. User defines variable: `x = int(input("Enter a number"))` as 100
2. User wants to find the fourth root of this number.

I have done research, but all I could find was  `sqrt(x)`

Thanks

Comment: Try `x**(1/y)`.

Comment: Ah thank  you, that has worked